# Woocommerce - Print text on Thank You page based on product attribute and payment method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

My question is exactly this:
 - Print text on Thank You page based on product attribute and payment method

I have this code that works perfectly:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'show_custom_text_by_variation_id', 1 ); 
function show_custom_text_by_variation_id( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Add whatever variation id you want below here.
        if ( isset( $item[ 'variation_id' ] ) && $item[ 'variation_id' ] == 9647 ) {
            echo '<br/>Example text - Thank you for buy VARIABLE A-9647 !<br/>';
        }
        if ( isset( $item[ 'variation_id' ] ) && $item[ 'variation_id' ] == 9648 ) {
            echo '<br/>Example text - Thank you for buy VARIABLE B-9648 !<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to return another text only when the condition of product choice is presented together with the type of payment for example bacs.

Example A :

- Product purchased - Variable 9647
- Selected payment method - Bacs

therefore only in this case the text on Thank You page will result:

- Example text - Thank you for buy VARIABLE A-9647 - With Payment Method Bacs!

or

Example B :

- Product purchased - Variable 9648
- Selected payment method - Bacs

therefore only in this case the text on Thank You page will result:

- Example text - Thank you for buy VARIABLE B-9648 - With Payment Method Bacs!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use: `$order->get_payment_method();`

```php
function action_woocommerce_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    // Get $order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Get items
    $items = $order->get_items();

    // Set variable
    $found = false;

    // Set variable
    $output = '';

    // Loop
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        // Add whatever variation id you want below here.
        if ( isset( $item[ 'variation_id' ] ) && $item[ 'variation_id' ] == 9647 ) {
            $output = 'Thank you for buy VARIABLE A-9647';
            $found = true;
            break;
        }

        if ( isset( $item[ 'variation_id' ] ) && $item[ 'variation_id' ] == 9648 ) {
            $output = 'Thank you for buy VARIABLE B-9648';
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Get payment method
    $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();

    // Payment method = basc & found = true
    if ( $payment_method == 'bacs' && $found ) {
        $output .= ' YOUR PAYMENT IS BACS';
    }

    // Print result
    echo $output;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'action_woocommerce_thankyou', 10, 1 );
```

---

**EDIT**

> show text on top of page, before the order details

```
function change_order_received_text( $str, $order ) {
    // Get items
    $items = $order->get_items();

    // Set variable
    $found = false;

    // Loop
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        // Add whatever variation id you want below here.
        if ( isset( $item[ 'variation_id' ] ) && $item[ 'variation_id' ] == 9647 ) {
            $str = 'Thank you for buy VARIABLE A-9647';
            $found = true;
            break;
        }

        if ( isset( $item[ 'variation_id' ] ) && $item[ 'variation_id' ] == 9648 ) {
            $str = 'Thank you for buy VARIABLE B-9648';
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Get payment method
    $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();

    // Payment method = basc & found = true
    if ( $payment_method == 'bacs' && $found ) {
        $str .= ' YOUR PAYMENT IS BACS';
    }

    return $str;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'change_order_received_text', 10, 2 );
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Hi 7uc1f3r - your code is fine. It is I who explained myself wrong.
if they choose the BACS payment the thank you text will be" Thank you for buy VARIABLE YOUR PAYMENT IS BACS "
While if they choose another payment method for example paypal or stripe the text will be "Thank you for buy VARIABLE".
I think it is not important what the other payment methods are, the important thing and that the condition changes only in the case of bacs. I hope I explained myself. Thanks

Comment: My code must work when they choose "VARIABLE A or B" and a payment other than bacs (like PapPal) and must return the text: Thank you for buy VARIABLE A. While with your code it is okay to return the test: "Thank you you for buy VARIABLE YOUR PAYMENT IS BACS '", but it no longer returns the text in the initial case.

Comment: Now it's perfect. I can only afford one last solution: in your code the text is printed at the bottom of everything (after billing details) it is possible to print it at the top, that is before the order details. thanks

Comment: yes, use 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text' instead of 'woocommerce_thankyou', see EDIT

Comment: There is something wrong, the text is no longer printed !!

Comment: here it just works in both cases, see attached picture

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211098/discussion-between-dom-and-7uc1f3r).

Comment: A conflict with the same hook is specific to your setup or website, my answer is general so that it can be used for other users on stackoverflow as well.  Therefore, the answer should not be modified in my opinion because it generally works.

Comment: Thanks Mr 7uc1f3r. I solved it by resuming your first code and setting the priority to 1
 - add_action ('woocommerce_thankyou', 'action_woocommerce_thankyou', 1);

Comment: If you have additional questions, don't edit my answer, just open a new post. Thank you